# My app is getting a KitKat status bar transparency on Lollipop devices

Tags: android

So I'm developing an app using Android Studio and my Galaxy s6 (5.0.2) and I'm trying to get a theme like [this one, where the status bar is transparent over the navagation drawer.](http://www.android4devs.com/2014/12/how-to-make-material-design-navigation-drawer.html) Seems simple enough, but on my device I'm getting a gradient KitKaty transparency, and its over the nav drawer, but requires a bit of scrolling first. Basically it looks terrible, and I was wondering where I'm going wrong?

[Here are the screenshots (apologies, I don't have the reputation to upload directly).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GTpvw.jpg)

And here is my values-v21/styles.xml: `

```
<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#FFFFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">#eee</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primaryColor</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/darkPrimaryColor</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accentColor</item>
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/second_grey</item>

  <!--here is what I've added to try to get transparency -->
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>

</style>
```

`

Thanks so much for your help!

EDIT: Its running perfectly on my Nexus 7 2013 (5.1.1), I'm stumped!

Comment: "Basically it looks terrible" It looks good to me. Thanks for the link to that  tutorial! I'm having some problem with transparent status bar as well, I think the tutorial might help me.